# How to make a custom ellipse circle in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[image: An Ellipse like this]

I'm trying to create an ellipse circle. Is there any way to create it using custom painter or clipper?.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [percent_indicator](https://pub.dev/packages/percent_indicator).

Maybe also try to make its color a gradient.

Comment: A very good workaround. Thanks